# Equilibrium states during irreversible process

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium, reversibility

Is it possible for there to be equilibrium states during an irreversible process?   What about when $P_{in}=P_{ex}$ during an irreversible gas expansion?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/131347/why-is-thermodynamic-equilibrium-not-reached-by-the-system-during-a-thermodynami?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the link;  I would still like to know whether the particular situation I mentioned would meet the criteria for equilibrium (if T_sys=T_surr also).

Comment: Do you think that temperature and pressure are spatially uniform within a system experiencing an irreversible process, and that the ideal gas law applies throughout the system?  Do you think that temperature and pressure match those of the surroundings at the interface with the surroundings (e.g., an ideal reservoir and/or the inside face of a piston)?

Comment: You may have already read this article below, sorry but there are clues in the first paragraph based on the definition and implications of the word irreversible ( I consider this a homework type question, that's why I am not writing an answer) , instead I would ask you to please  read  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreversible_process